# How do I delete all messages in a discord channel with js?

Tags: python, discord.py

Using discord.py in python, I can do the following and it'll slowly delete all messages in a channel even if they're more than 2 weeks old:

```py
async def clear(self, ctx):

    length = await ctx.message.channel.history(limit=999).flatten()
    num = len(length)
    div = 100
    target = [num // div(1 if x < num % div else 0) for x in range(div)]

    for tar in target:
        async for message in ctx.message.channel.history(limit=tar):
            await ctx.message.channel.delete_messages([message])
```

How would I go about doing the same thing in javascript discord.js?

Comment: the logic is exactly same, read the [documentation for discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) then you should able to do it, if not then you probably need to study javascript first

Comment: There can be thousands or more messages in a channel. Instead of deleting them one by one and spamming Discord's API you'd be better of just deleting and creating the channel again.

Comment: it's an info channel and the text is not that big enough. problem is others are referencing to that channel so removing it is inconvenient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
message.channel.clone()
.then(() => message.channel.delete().catch(() => null)), 10000))
```

instead it will create new channel with same permissions and etc..

Answer (score 2):

This is the common function for it, however [bulkDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) does have 2 week limitation and 100 message limit.

```
async function clearChat (msg, numb) {
    const channel = msg.channel;
    const messageManager = channel.messages;
    const messages = await messageManager.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: numb });
    channel.bulkDelete(messages,true);

}
```

To call it just:

```
clearChat(msg, 100);
```

In your code